# AWS Glue Resolve Column Choice as Array or Struct

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

Run out of ideas on how to solve the following issue. A table in the Glue data catalog has this schema:

```
root
|-- _id: string
|-- _field: struct
|    |-- ref: choice
|    |    |-- array
|    |    |    |-- element: struct
|    |    |    |    |-- value: null
|    |    |    |    |-- key: string
|    |    |    |    |-- name: string
|    |    |-- struct
|    |    |    |-- value: null
|    |    |    |-- key: choice
|    |    |    |    |-- int
|    |    |    |    |-- string
|    |    |    |-- name: string
```

If I try to resolve the `ref` choice using

```
resolved = (
     df.
        resolveChoice(
            specs = [('_field.ref','cast:array')]
        )
)
```

I lose records.

Any ideas on how I could:

1. filter the DataFrame on whether `_field.ref` is an `array` or `struct`
2. convert `struct` records into an `array` or vice-versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem by using

```
resolved_df = ResolveChoice.apply(df, choice = "make_cols")
```

This will save `array` values in a new `ref_array` column and `struct` values in `ref_struct` column.

This allowed me to split the DataFrame by

```
resolved_df1 = resolved_df.filter(col("ref_array").isNotNull()).select(col("ref_array").alias("ref"))

resolved_df2 = resolved_df.filter(col("ref_struct").isNotNull()).select(col("ref_struct").alias("ref"))
```

After either converting the array to structs only (using `explode()`) or converting structs to an array using `array()`, recombine them